# how to unhide previously hidden folders after reinstalling windows7

Tags: windows-7

I am using windows 7 home basic now, but few days back i encountered a problem in my laptop. So i had to reinstall C drive, i.e. system drive. I had hidden some files in a folder using command prompt--- attrib +h +s foldername in another drive.. And now after reinstallation when i tried to unhide that folder it says Access denied. Please help me solve this problem. Need an urgent solution.

Answer (score -1):

Have u tried running the command prompt in Admin mode ?

I did faced such situations where right clicking on Command Prompt from start menu
and then choosing 'Run As Admin ...' solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

First you should unhide those folders by [ Alt+T -> Folder Options -> View } (if i am correct)
or go to control panel and "Folder Options" and then into "view" menu. You should see an option under Hidden Files and Folders-Show Hidden files, folders and drives. You should find your files in the respective drives you saved them into are not hidden. You can then edit their security options, as when you hide certain folders and reinstall an OS those folders' security is not given any privileges to any user so you might end up getting an error using CMD to unhide those folders.